# BCM.GPIO and BOARD.GPIO

Tags: pi-3, i2c, spi, rfid

For a school project I wanted to use a 128x64 OLED i2c OLED screen and a RFID reader. I tested everything separate and it worked, but when I wanted to join everything in my main program it failed, because the library for the OLED screen used BCM numbering and the library for the RFID reader used BOARD numbering (just like I did). Is there a way to fix this, I searched the internet but couldn't find anyone with the same problem.

i2c library: https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_Python_SSD1306
RFID library: https://github.com/mxgxw/MFRC522-python (uses SPI)

Some extra information: it's a raspberry pi 3 and I use python 3. (I don't know if that's important to know, but better safe then sorry)

Comment: You can do a mapping during your setup, [this table](https://pinout.xyz/) might be useful for you to map the BCM to Board or vice versa.

Comment: @hcheung I understand that, but that is not my problem, I know that site, but it's impossible to change all the pins in the library

Answer (score 1):

The library `Adafruit_Python_SSD1306` is based on another library `Adafruit_GPIO`, if you read the [Adafruit_GPIO github source code](https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_Python_GPIO/blob/master/Adafruit_GPIO/GPIO.py) on `get_platform_gpio(**keywords)` function, you will noticed that it is actually just a wrapper of `RPi.GPIO` package, and returning a `RPi.GPIO` object. The `RPi.GPIO` does has the method `setmode()` for setting BOARD or BCM ping numbering, so you can map or specify the mode by passing a `**keywords` using the follow code:

```
import RPi.GPIO
import Adafruit_GPIO as GPIO

gpio = GPIO.get_platform_gpio(mode=RPi.GPIO.BOARD)
```

Now use the gpio object like normal, but with Pi board numbering.